# Steam library folder must be on Executable filesystem

Tags: chroot, sd-card, chrome-book, chrome-os, steam

I am running Debian 9 via Crouton on an Intel Chromebook. I've had some difficulties with bash and the display, however I resolved these. I installed Steam, and the games work on it, however I only have 16GB on the eMMC chip inside the computer.

I would like to download Steam games on an external SD card. Inside the Chroot, the SD card I have inside the built in slot is mounted in /media which has a symbolic link to /var/host/media/removable/USB (USB being the name of the SD card), however when I try to add it as an extra Steam games location, Steam tells me that the "new Steam library folder must be on a filesystem with execute permissions".

Just to be clear, I am able to read and modify contents on the SD card via the Chroot. How can I make the SD card usable by Steam?

Comment: What are the permissions of the directory on which the filesystem is mounted?  Does the underlying directory have `+x`?

Comment: i dont know, when i launch crouton, the directory is automatically mounted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SD card is mounted with the `noexec` option (or perhaps `user`, which includes `noexec`). You need to remount it with the `exec` option explicitly; you might find it easiest to add an entry to `/etc/fstab` with the appropriate options (`user,exec` should do the trick).

Comment: My fstab file is empty, it just says # unconfigured

Comment: Yes, which is why I said you'd have to *add* an entry. See also [issue 3579](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/3579) re the empty `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: i ended up opening gnome-disks using gksudo (doing it without root gave me the quark 4 error), disabled automatic mounting options which revealed fixed options within fstab, and added users(with the s) and exec, and only this way it worked. your answer is correct, but i wanted to mention these details as well